# Selective conditional formatting when midnight is time in the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have created a sheet where the first column is an hourly timeline starting with a user entered time and date. The user inputs the time and date in cell F4. Subsequently the timeline starts in cell A2 with the first time being equal to what was entered in F4.

Each cell below it adds one hour by virtue of the formula `=A2+1/24`.

What I would like to do now is to conditionally format any cells where the time is midnight, to show both date and time.

For example

- if the data entered by the user in F4 was "1/2/2016 06:00", what is displayed in A2 is **06:00**. A3 shows **07:00**, etc.
- This progresses until 00:00 representing 1/3/2016 00:00. I would like to conditionally format it so that when "00:00" is the value showing in the cell, it automatically conditionally formats to show **1/3/2016 00:00**, and the correct date for each subsequent occurrence of midnight.

Answer (score 0):

1. select your range you want to conditionally format
2. go to home - conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula to determine which cell to format
3. Enter the formula `=HOUR(A1)=0` *(where A1 is your active cell)*
4. Go to Format - Number; Select custom and enter your format code (`m/d/yyyy hh:mm` in your example)

Comment: Does this work for Google Sheets? I don't see the option you described in no. 2. I know the question is tagged with Excel, but I am curious to know about this.

Comment: I don't think it works in Google Sheets. Also there you can change only colour with conditional formatting, not the number format.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but that's all I can see, too.